# WPF Multiple ItemSources?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemssource

Is it possible to have multiple ItemSources for a single control?

Given the code below:

```
<ComboBox Margin="137,101,169,183" ItemsSource="{Binding collection}"   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"            
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Command="{Binding CheckCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

The TextBlock within the ComboBox DataTemplate requires data from another property within the VM than that of the ComboBox.  How can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)-FindAncestor to reach up the visual tree and grab a different DataContext.

For example (assuming the command is what you want):

```
Command=”{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=CheckCommand}”
```

[This](http://wangmo.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/binding-the-relativesource/) should also serve as a good resource.

Edit: Typo and resources.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I've tried <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=SelectedItem}"  With Window being the top level holding the datacontext that I need.

Comment: Have it working now.  It should be Path=DataContext.SelectedItem  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If i remember correctly, DataTemplates run within their own scope and cannot directly use ElementNames defined outside the `DataTemplate`. You could however get around it by using `StaticResource` and referring to that directly from `TextBlock` inside the template.

I haven't tried Ragepotatos's approach to go outside DataTemplate scope but would love to know if that works out for you too.